# Robot Framework: Create template

Tags: python, robotframework

I have following code which open 2 browsers and closing at end. I want to make it as tempplate and reuse it. How to achieve it?

```
*** Test Cases ***
PhpTravels_Net
    : FOR    ${browser}    IN    @{listBrowser}
    \    Open Browser    https://planet2.swift.com/Pages/default.aspx    ${browser}
    \    Log    ${browser}
    Close All Browsers
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: just dump it under some keyword name in resource file and call it on test cases

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Note that I'm not using a list as you did, and set `Close All Browsers` to `Teardown`.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
PhpTravels_Net
    [Template]    Open Browser Template
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    firefox
    chrome

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser Template
    [Arguments]    ${browser}
    Open Browser    https://planet2.swift.com/Pages/default.aspx    ${browser}
    Log    ${browser}
```

Comment: The statemnet under for loop is different between test cases. How to achieve it?

Comment: By comparing values and using `Run Keyword If`. It's difficult to help more if you don't provide any additional information.

Did the template answer help with your original problem?